# Radius of one of a conical frustum's circular planes, given the other's radius, the volume, and the angle?

Tags: volume

I'm trying to find the radius of the larger of the two circular planes of a frustum of a right circular cone.

[image: right circular cone]

I know the volume of the frustum, the radius of the smaller circle, and the angle between the sides and vertical. What's the formula to find the larger circle's radius?

Comment: Sorry, [here's a picture](http://i.imgur.com/C5AFUDL.png) — I'm trying to solve for R, if I have all the other values shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice in the given figure, consider right triangles

The normal height of the smaller cone (cap of the frustum) $$=r\cot\alpha$$
Volume of smaller cone with circular base of radius $r$ & normal height $r\cot\alpha$ $$V_1=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2(r\cot\alpha)=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^3\cot\alpha$$

The normal height of the larger cone (frustum with its cap) $$=R\cot\alpha$$
Volume of larger cone with circular base of radius $R$ & normal height $R\cot\alpha$ $$V_2=\frac{1}{3}\pi R^2(R\cot\alpha)=\frac{1}{3}\pi R^3\cot\alpha$$

Now, the volume of the frustum of cone 
$$V=\text{(volume of larger cone)} - \text{(volume of smaller cone)}$$
$$V=V_1-V_2$$ $$V=\frac{1}{3}\pi R^3\cot\alpha-\frac{1}{3}\pi r^3\cot\alpha$$
$$R^3=\frac{3}{\pi\cot\alpha}\left(V+\frac{1}{3}\pi r^3\cot\alpha\right)=\frac{3V}{\pi\cot \alpha}+r^3$$
$$\color{red}{R=\left(\frac{3V}{\pi\cot\alpha}+r^3\right)^{1/3}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help Harish, although I'm not getting results I'd expect. @hardmath, can you help me with the correct formula based on your comment?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not getting sensible answers. For example: 
If r=20 mm, V=7500 cubic mm, and a=6º, 
then cot a=9.51436445422; 
3*7500/(π*9.51436445422)=752.753636209; 
752.753636209–20^3=-7247.24636379; 
-7247.24636379^(1/3)=-19.3519325512=R. 
That's a negative number and even if it wasn't, it'd be smaller than r, when it should be larger. Am I doing any of the math wrong, or is there something wrong with the formula? (Apologies for the formatting!)

Comment: Here's a bit better formatting with my test values:
$$
R=\left( \dfrac {3\times 7500} {\pi \times 9.51436445422}-20^{3}\right) ^{1 / 3}
$$

Comment: @Sam:  Yes, there is also a sign mistake in the second step.  I'll fix it.

Comment: @hardmath: thanks for editing

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's working well now!